# SwiftUI store and update Custom object in UserDefault array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui, storage

I'm making a pretty complex SwiftUI app which lets you register walks.
The UI itself works great but I can't for the life of me figure out how to properly store data locally with UserDefaults.

I am trying to store a User object, with a child Profile object.
I'm separately trying to store a DogArray object which has a list of Dog objects.
Like this:

```
 - User Defaults
   - User
     - Profile
   - DogArray
     - Dog
       - Walk
       - Walk
     - Dog
       - Walk
     ...
```

I am able to store the User and Profile objects but I first have to navigate back from the ProfileView before closing the app for them to be stored. I can also store the Dog objects in the DogArray but it doesn't seem to update the UserDefaults when I change a Dog in the DogDetailView, and their data isn't stored when the app is relaunched, only the DogArray.

I realize it would be much easier to clone the project than try to puzzle together my code snippets. I've uploaded a minimum viable example to github where you can try it yourself. Thanks

https://github.com/kimnordin/WalkApp

If you run it and change something you'll see it's not stored properly, or at all.

Here are my **DogArray**, **User**, and **Walk** **objects** (walks can be stored in a Dog).

**DogArray**

```
class DogArray: ObservableObject, Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case list
    }
    @Published var list: [Dog] {
        didSet {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(list) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Dogs")
            }
        }
    }
    init() {
        if let dog = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Dogs") {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let decoded = try? decoder.decode([Dog].self, from: dog) {
                self.list = decoded
                return
            }
        }
        self.list = []
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        list = try container.decode([Dog].self, forKey: .list)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(list, forKey: .list)
    }
    
    var count : Int {
        return list.count
    }
    
    func addDog(dog: Dog) {
        list.append(dog)
    }
    
    func clearDogs() {
        list.removeAll()
    }
    
    func deleteDog(index: Int){
        list.remove(at: index)
    }

    func entry(index: Int) -> Dog? {
        if index >= 0 && index <= list.count {
            return list[index]
        }
        return nil
    }
}

class Dog: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name, image, startDisplayDate, walkArray, firstSelect, secondSelect
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var image: UIImage
    var startDisplayDate: Date? = Date()
    @Published var walkArray = [Walk]()
    @Published var firstSelect: Bool = false
    @Published var secondSelect: Bool = false
    
    init(name: String, image: UIImage, startDisplayDate: Date? = Date(), walkArray: [Walk] = [Walk](), firstSelect: Bool = false, secondSelect: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.startDisplayDate = startDisplayDate
        self.walkArray = walkArray
        self.firstSelect = firstSelect
        self.secondSelect = secondSelect
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        let dataImage = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .image)
        if let uiImage = dataImage.toImage() {
            image = uiImage
        }
        else {
            image = UIImage(systemName: "questionmark.circle.fill")!
        }
        startDisplayDate = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .startDisplayDate)
        walkArray = try container.decode([Walk].self, forKey: .walkArray)
        firstSelect = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .firstSelect)
        secondSelect = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .secondSelect)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(image.toData(), forKey: .image)
        try container.encode(startDisplayDate, forKey: .startDisplayDate)
        try container.encode(walkArray, forKey: .walkArray)
        try container.encode(firstSelect, forKey: .firstSelect)
        try container.encode(secondSelect, forKey: .secondSelect)
    }
    
    func walk(time: Date, firstSelect: Bool, secondSelect: Bool) {
        let walk = Walk(time: time, firstAction: firstSelect, secondAction: secondSelect)
        walkArray.append(walk)
        sortWalks()
    }
    
    func sortWalks() {
        walkArray = walkArray.sortWalksByDates()
    }
}
```

**User**

```
class User: ObservableObject {
    @Published var profile: Profile {
        didSet {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(profile) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Profile")
            }
        }
    }
    init() {
        if let profile = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Profile") {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            if let decoded = try? decoder.decode(Profile.self, from: profile) {
                self.profile = decoded
                return
            }
        }
        self.profile = Profile()
    }
}

struct Profile: Identifiable, Codable { // <-- Profile As Struct
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case walkColor, firstColor, secondColor
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    var walkColor: Color? = Color.orange
    var firstColor: Color? = Color.blue
    var secondColor: Color? = Color.pink
    
    init() {}
    
    init(walkColor: Color? = Color.orange, firstColor: Color? = Color.blue, secondColor: Color? = Color.pink) {
        self.walkColor = walkColor
        self.firstColor = firstColor
        self.secondColor = secondColor
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        let walkData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .walkColor)
        let firstData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .firstColor)
        let secondData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .secondColor)
        walkColor = dataToColor(walkData)
        firstColor = dataToColor(firstData)
        secondColor = dataToColor(secondData)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        let walkUiColor = walkColor?.toUiColor() ?? .orange
        let firstUiColor = firstColor?.toUiColor() ?? .blue
        let secondUiColor = secondColor?.toUiColor() ?? .systemPink
        let walkData = toData(walkUiColor)
        let firstData = toData(firstUiColor)
        let secondData = toData(secondUiColor)
        
        try container.encodeIfPresent(walkData, forKey: .walkColor)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(firstData, forKey: .firstColor)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(secondData, forKey: .secondColor)
    }
    
    func dataToColor(_ data: Data) -> Color? {
        do {
            if let dataColor = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? UIColor {
                return Color(dataColor)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func toData(_ uiColor: UIColor) -> Data? {
        do {
            let colorData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: uiColor, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            return colorData
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }
}

enum SelectedColor {
    case walk
    case first
    case second
    case none
}
```

**Walk**

```
struct Walk: Codable {
    var time: Date
    var firstAction: Bool?
    var secondAction: Bool?
}
```

**Here's where I introduce the User and DogArray objects when the App launches**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct WalkAppApp: App {
    @StateObject private var dogData = DogArray()
    @StateObject private var user = User()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            DogListView(viewModel: DogListViewModel())
                .environmentObject(user)
                .environmentObject(dogData)
        }
    }
}
```

**And here's the first view that's displayed in the App**

```
struct DogListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    @EnvironmentObject var dogs: DogArray
    @State private var presentNew = false
    @State private var presentProfile = false
    var body: some View { //MARK: View
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<dogs.list.count, id: \.self) { dog in
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        NavigationLink(destination: DogDetailView(dog: dogs.list[dog])) {
                        }
                        .opacity(0)
                        DogListRow(dog: dogs.list[dog])
                    }
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
            .background(NavigationLink(
                destination: NewDogView(),
                isActive: $presentNew) {
            })
            .background(NavigationLink(
                destination: ProfileView(),
                isActive: $presentProfile) {
            })
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Dogs"))
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    HStack {
                                        Button("Profile") {
                                            presentProfile = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                , trailing:
                                    HStack {
                                        Button("+") {
                                            presentNew = true
                                        }
                                    }
            )
        }
    }
    private func move(at indexSet: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        dogs.list.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: destination)
    }
    func delete(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
        dogs.list.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
}
```

**The DogListRow View**

```
struct DogListRow: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    @ObservedObject var dog: Dog
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Image(uiImage: dog.image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .padding()
            VStack(spacing: 4) {
                Text(dog.name)
                    .font(.title)
                    .lineLimit(2)
                if !dog.walkArray.isEmpty {
                    if let firstWalk = dog.walkArray.first {
                        if let time = firstWalk.time.timeToString() {
                            VStack {
                                Text("Latest Walk")
                                    .font(.footnote)
                                Text(time)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            VStack(spacing: 3) {
                if dog.walkArray.first?.firstAction == true {
                    Text("1")
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 35)
                        .background(user.profile.firstColor)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                }
                if dog.walkArray.first?.secondAction == true {
                    Text("2")
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 35)
                        .background(user.profile.secondColor)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The NewDogView to make a new Dog**

```
struct NewDogView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @EnvironmentObject var dogs: DogArray
    @State var alertItem: AlertItem?
    @State var dogCreated: Bool = false
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var uiImage: UIImage? = nil
    @State var showAction: Bool = false
    @State var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            if (uiImage == nil) {
                Image(systemName: "camera.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 130, height: 130)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        displayImagePicker()
                    }
            } else {
                Image(uiImage: uiImage!)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        displayActionSheet()
                    }
            }
            TextField("Enter the Dogs name", text: $name)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 40, leading: 20, bottom: 20, trailing: 20))
        }
        .fixFlickering()
        .alert(item: $alertItem, content: { alertItem in
            Alert(title: alertItem.title,
                  message: alertItem.message,
                  dismissButton: .default(alertItem.buttonTitle))
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker, onDismiss: {
            dismissImagePicker()
        }, content: {
            ImagePicker(presenting: $showImagePicker, uiImage: $uiImage)
        })
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showAction) {
            sheet
        }
        Group {
            Button(action: {
                createDog(name: name, image: uiImage)
                if dogCreated {
                    self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Add dog")
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 60)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            })
            .padding(.horizontal, 8).lineLimit(1).minimumScaleFactor(0.4)
            .background(Color.orange)
            .cornerRadius(30)
        }
    }
    private func createDog(name: String, image: UIImage? = nil) {
        if isDogValid(name: name, image: image) {
            dogs.addDog(dog: Dog(name: name, image: image!))
            dogCreated = true
        }
        else {
            dogCreated = false
        }
    }
    var sheet: ActionSheet {
        ActionSheet(
            title: Text("Action"),
            message: Text("Update Image"),
            buttons: [
                .default(Text("Change"), action: {
                    self.dismissActionSheet()
                    self.displayImagePicker()
                }),
                .cancel(Text("Close"), action: {
                    self.dismissActionSheet()
                }),
                .destructive(Text("Remove"), action: {
                    self.dismissActionSheet()
                    self.uiImage = nil
                })
            ])
    }
    
    func displayActionSheet() {
        showAction = true
    }
    
    func dismissActionSheet() {
        showAction = false
    }
    
    func displayImagePicker() {
        showImagePicker = true
    }
    
    func dismissImagePicker() {
        showImagePicker = false
    }
    
    func isDogValid(name: String, image: UIImage?) -> Bool {
        if name != "" && image != nil {
            return true
        }
        else if name == "" && image != nil  {
            alertItem = AlertContext.NewDog.noName
        }
        else if name != "" && image == nil {
            alertItem = AlertContext.NewDog.noImage
        }
        else {
            alertItem = AlertContext.NewDog.noNameNoImage
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

**The Profile View where you can edit the color of the Buttons**

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    @State var permProfile: Profile = Profile(walkColor: Color.orange, firstColor: Color.blue, secondColor: Color.pink)
    @State private var presentModal = false
    @State var selectedColor = SelectedColor.none
    
    let colors = [Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green, Color.orange, Color.pink, Color.yellow, Color.red, Color.white, Color.gray, Color.black]
    
    @ViewBuilder func ColorView(color: Color) -> some View {
        (color)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .onTapGesture {
                switch selectedColor {
                case .walk:
                    permProfile.walkColor = color
                case .first:
                    permProfile.firstColor = color
                case .second:
                    permProfile.secondColor = color
                default: break
                }
            }
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                Text("Edit Selection Items")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                .padding(5)
                Text("Change the button color")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 0, bottom: 5, trailing: 0))
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        presentModal = true
                        selectedColor = .first
                    }) {
                        Text("1")
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .background(permProfile.firstColor)
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        presentModal = true
                        selectedColor = .walk
                    }) {
                        Text("Walk")
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .background(permProfile.walkColor)
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        presentModal = true
                        selectedColor = .second
                    }) {
                        Text("2")
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .background(permProfile.secondColor)
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            if presentModal {
                ModalView() {
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack(spacing: 40) {
                            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                                ColorView(color: color)
                                    .frame(minWidth: 20, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 20, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } closeModal: {
                    presentModal = false
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            permProfile = user.profile
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            user.profile = permProfile
        }
    }
}
```

**DogDetailView that is shown when you select a dog in the list**

```
struct DogDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dog: Dog
    var body: some View { //MARK: View
        // Dog Section
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Image(uiImage: dog.image)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 110, height: 110)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(dog.name)
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 8)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom: 8, trailing: 10))
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<dog.walkArray.count, id: \.self) { walk in
                        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            TimeRow(walk: dog.walkArray[walk])
                        }
                    }
                }
                Group {
                    WalkSectionView(dog: dog)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Dog` is a class. Your `list` in `DogArray` only stores references. When the properties of a Dog change, its reference remains unchanged, the `list` doesn't change and the `didSet` is not called. Make `Dog` a `struct` and use `Binding` for your DogDetailView.

Comment: Use class + @ObservableObject for your ViewModel, not for your Model. Otherwise your ViewModel cannot be notified of changes to your Model

Comment: @Adrien It makes sense to use a struct for the Dog objects. What do you mean regarding the ViewModel? Do you mean that my models should not be @ObservablesObjects? How should my ViewModel be updated of it’s changes, should it contain the Dog and User @EnvironmentObjects?

Comment: I'm going to write a longer answer.

Comment: @Adrien Appreciate it! I might be tying together my Property Wrappers incorrectly, but as I want the User and DogArray to be globally accessible I assumed they should be EnvironmentObjects. As i understand Binding it should mostly be used to handle changes between a parent and child view, not several views. How would I then have an Object accessible from anywhere in the app that still updates the UI and the UserDefaults?

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project `Dog` is a class. Your array `list`, in your `DogArray` class, only stores references. When the properties of a `Dog` change, its reference remains unchanged, the array doesn't change and the `didSet` is not called.

I simplified your project to make the problem more understandable:

```
struct DogList: View {
    @StateObject var dogs = DogArray(list: ["John", "Bob"].map(Dog.init))
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(dogs.list.indices) {index in
                NavigationLink(destination: DogDetail(dog: dogs.list[index])) {
                    Text(dogs.list[index].name)
                    Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(dogs.list[index].favorite ? .red : .gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DogDetail: View {
    @ObservedObject var dog: Dog
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(dog.name)
                
            Button {
                dog.favorite.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(dog.favorite ? .red : .gray)
            }
        }.font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

class Dog: ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    @Published var favorite = false
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}


class DogArray: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [Dog] {
        didSet {
            print("Array changes")
        }
    }
    init(list: [Dog]) {
        self.list = list
    }
}
```

Here, when the user taps the heart in the `DogDetail` View, the `Dog` changed, the `DogDetail`'s body is redrawn (because Dog is observable). But the `DogList` is not invalidated. The parent view does not know that the Dog has changed.

We have only three things to do to resolve problem.

1. Make `Dog` a `struct`
2. `@ObservedObject var dog: Dog` -> `@Binding var dog: Dog`
3. `DogDetail(dog: dogs.list[index])` -> `DogDetail(dog: $dogs.list[index])`

Now it works.

Your problem is a little more complicated than this example because you use `ObservableObject` for three things: your Model (here `Dog` : to be avoided), your Store (here `DogArray`), and a ViewModel (which I can't see well the usefulness).

You should choose I think between using a global Store (your `DogArray`) that you inject with EnvironmentObject at the top of your view hierarchy. Views that need it get it. All share the same object.

Or really switch to an architecture with ViewModels, and in this case it's up to each of them to manage access to the Model.

It could go something like this:

```
import SwiftUI
struct DogList: View {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var list: [DogDetail.ViewModel]
        init(dogs: [Dog]) {
            list = []
            list = dogs.map { DogDetail.ViewModel(dog: $0, parent: self) }
        }
        func save() {
            print("list saved")
        }
    }
    @StateObject var vm = DogList.ViewModel(dogs:["John", "Bob"].map(Dog.init))
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(vm.list, id: \.dog.id) {detail in
                NavigationLink(destination: DogDetail(vm: detail)) {
                    DogRow(vm: detail)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DogRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: DogDetail.ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text(vm.dog.name)
        Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            .foregroundColor(vm.dog.favorite ? .red : .gray)
    }
}

struct DogDetail: View {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        let parent: DogList.ViewModel
        @Published var dog: Dog {
            didSet {
                print("a dog changed")
                parent.objectWillChange.send()
                parent.save()
            }
        }
        init(dog: Dog, parent: DogList.ViewModel) {
            self.dog = dog
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    var dog: Dog { vm.dog }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(dog.name)
            Button {
                vm.dog.favorite.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(dog.favorite ? .red : .gray)
            }
        }.font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

## Edit (Combine)

You may not like when the "parent" gives a reference of itself to its "children" : `DogDetail.ViewModel(dog: $0, parent: self)`

You can also use Combine and make `DogList.ViewModel` subscribe to changes in `DogDetail.ViewModel.dog` :

```
import Combine
struct DogList: View {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var list: [DogDetail.ViewModel] {
            didSet {
                subscribeToChanges()
            }
        }
        func subscribeToChanges() {
            self.cancellable = list.publisher
                .flatMap { $0.dogDidChange }
                .sink { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.objectWillChange.send()
                    self?.save()
                }
        }
        var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
        init(dogs: [Dog]) {
            list = dogs.map { DogDetail.ViewModel(dog: $0) }
            subscribeToChanges()
        }
        func save() {
            print("list saved :")
            for dogVM in list {
                print(dogVM.dog.favorite)
            }
        }
    }
// ....//
}
```

You need a `dogDidChange` publisher in `DogDetail.ViewModel` :

```
struct DogDetail: View {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        var dogDidChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
        @Published var dog: Dog {
            didSet {
                print("a dog changed")
                dogDidChange.send()
            }
        }
        init(dog: Dog) {
            self.dog = dog
        }
    }
//...//
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. I realize my ViewModels are very unnecessary, I think my real issue is handling the state wrappers to properly update the parent state of User and DogArray. I removed all my VM's and combined all logic in each view. I also changed Profile to be a Struct, which now stores the changed values made to the Profile. Though I am not sure how to update the Profile object when it changes, as I currently have to do it when the view is closed. As for the Dog object I am not sure how I should handle a struct across such a large project. I updated my question and git with the changes

Comment: @Kim : When you edit your question because you tried new things, leave your original code and question and place your changes in a dedicated paragraph (at the end for example). Otherwise we no longer understand the answers that were posted. You can take the opportunity to upvote the answers that were useful to you.

Comment: That's very true, I will change my approach going forward. Also I just need 1 more rep for upvoting, trust me I've tried upvoting your replies a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you adding walk just set explicitly dog to the list like below hope it work fine

```
Button(action: {
                dog.walk(time: Date(), firstSelect: dog.firstSelect, secondSelect: dog.secondSelect)
                dog.firstSelect = false
                dog.secondSelect = false
                dog.sortWalks()
                guard let i = dogData.list.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == dog.id})else{
                    return
                }
                dogData.list[i] = dog
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Walk")
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 60)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            })
```

Comment: It might work if the Model is a struct. But for me it's a way of not facing the problem. You shouldn't have to search for the object you want to modify. We have @Binding for that sort of thing.

Comment: @Adrien did you test it ? in my case it work fine, it work because actual data updated and not only reference in list

Comment: Ok. I still think we shouldn't use `firstIndex`. Here it will not be a performance problem, (the user will not be managing millions of dogs and when it does there will have been other problems - like the fact that the images are stored in UserDefaults, for example ). But it's just that with the right architecture we shouldn't have to do that.